# Django-Allauth remove email field in signup form

Tags: django, django-forms, django-allauth

I only use Linked-In as means to authenticate. When the user gives permission in Linked-In, he get's send to my own form so I can gather extra information. But it seems Allauth only lets me add fields to the default form using:

```
ACCOUNT_SIGNUP_FORM_CLASS = 'myapp.forms.MySignUpForm'
```

But the email field is always visible (and filled in with the email from Linked-In). Is it true that I have no way of dropping this field? I don't want the user to be able to change his email into something else than his Linked-In email.